# Set format to cursor.fetchall() result

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

Im working with mysql.connection library to Python and I have this method:

```
query = ("select " + columns + " from " + table)
self.cursor.execute(query)
data = self.cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print row
```

In my print row, I get something like this:

```
(u'Kabul', u'AFG', u'Kabol', 1780000)
```

I would like to get it as a string, this result:

```
Kabul AFG Kabol 1780000
```

I can do this:

```
print row[0] + ' ' + row[1] + row[2] + ' ' + row[3]
```

But it will not work if the user sets a query with less than 4 columns or more than 4.

I also was thinking about a loop in my tuple, but I get this result:

```
Kabul
AFG
Kabol
1780000
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `join` but will run into errors when joining a list of mixed unicode and integers. Use the built in `str` function and list comprehension to create your intended output.

```
print ' '.join(str(x) for x in row)
```

Comment: This work well =) Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add that I get an error of unicode or something like that, I resolve with this:

    print " ".join(str(unicode(c).encode('utf-8')) for c in row)

Answer (score 2):

If `row` is a `tuple` you could join every value in it using space:

```
print " ".join(row)
# Kabul AFG Kabol 1780000
```

So, it doesn't matter how many columns a user has selected, it will always join what `row` has.

**UPDATE:**

Above code works only if the values in row are string, so you need to first convert values to string and then join

```
print " ".join(map(str, row))
```

Comment: This will fail if anything in the tuple is not a string.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the answer.